# Is $A=\left\{x:x \text{ belongs to } (1,2) \cup [2,3)\right\}$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

My question is
whether the given set
$$A=\left\{x:x \text{ belongs to } (1,2) \cup [2,3)\right\}$$is connected?
If so then how?
I know $x$ belongs to $(1,2)$ implies that $1<x<2$ and $x$ belongs to $[2,3)$ implies that $2\leq x<3$.
So these two are "not" disjoint sets since they have at least one element in common, i.e., $2$.

Comment: 2 isn't in the 1st set.

Comment: $A=(1,3]$ and it is connected.

Comment: That set itself is $(1,2)\cup[2,3)=(1,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

A set $A$ is connected if there are no Two non-empty separated subsets $B$ and $C$ such that $A = B \cup C$
And according to Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" Theorem 2.47:

> A subset E of the real line $R^1$ is connected if and only if it has the following property: If $x \in E, y \in E,\space and \space x < z < y, then \space z \in E$

Which clearly hold here.